# lubuntu notify-send remove limit of 21?

Tags: notification, lubuntu, libnotify, notify-send

sending notifications with notify-send in lubuntu

```
notify-send -i error -t 1000 "Error" "error notification"
```

I can send only 21 of them, after that no more notifications sent, the only way to receive more notifications is to click on the panel where there's a letter with the number 21 and then click on the button "clear all notifications".

Is there a way to avoid the need to go clicking the button, also is there a way to remove at all that letter with number of notifications received?

UPDATE: I realize that notification-daemon (0.7.3) is used. I downloaded the sources and edited the source code (nd-queue.c - on_bubble_destroyed) to do not buffer but always destroy the bubbles but I would prefer another way...

Comment: Does this apply to you? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/notification-daemon/+bug/927031

Comment: No, I have no crashes and this seems not a bug but just a limitation to maximum 21 notifications and after that I have to manually clear the buffer clicking the button "clear all notifications" to have it accept new notifications

Answer (score 1):

I answered this for a different issue [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/166512/65315), but it will also solve your problem. In short, remove `notification-daemon` and install `xfce4-notifyd`. It won't require you to clear the notifications.

Comment: I tried xfce4-notifyd but it doesn't pop up the message if I'm full screen (my case), even if I set urgency critical.